# Saving peoples progress on flash games onto a site

Tags: php, mysql, flash

I know there are sites out there when you log on to their account they can play swf games or otherwise flash games on the site so whenever they go to another computer they can continue their progress without restarting just by logging onto their account.

I would like to know how they do this. So I can added it to my site. I honestly have no clue where to start to learn this. Any help leading me to the right direction. Or if you can give me some code. I would appreciate it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'd need to create a php/mysql based API for developers. Whatever functions you want them to be able to call in flash to save data, you'll need to code in PHP. You'll also probably have to code something to access the API, in the form of Actionscript code.

It's not something really easy that you could just "add to your site", probably the biggest thing you'd have to do is get developers to integrate it to their games. There's (unfortunately!) no magic self-implementing code which a flash developer can add to their game which has a standard serverside library, for saving data.

You'll probably want to take a look at [this tutorial](http://particletree.com/features/how-to-add-an-api-to-your-web-service/) for the basics of how to go about implementing this.

Comment: Thank you I know it will not be easy I should now when I make coding from scratch on my site. Most of the time it doesn't work right away and 3 to 4 days or reworking and it works fine. Though thank you again.